# .gif changes size on mousover

Tags: html, css

I want a gif to start when the mouse is over an image. It *does* start when you hover, but it changes to its original size, making it smaller. I want ".static" and ".static:hover" to be the same size. I used:

```
.container4 {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1080px;
    height:500px;
    padding-top:100px;
    background-color:floralwhite;
}

.static {
    position:absolute;
    background: white;
    height: 140px;
    width: 300px;
}

.static:hover {
    opacity:0;
    height: 140px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```
<div class="container4">
    <img class="static" src="imagenes/acampada.jpg">
    <img class="hover" src="media/acampada.gif">
</div>
```

So the post doesn't get cluttered with code, I put the whole thing [here](https://codepen.io/novk/pen/rNVwZPR) in case you need it.

Comment: Is a dot missing in the first `static` section?

Comment: can you  please show your JS codes?

Comment: try provide more of your html code, and if you are using a JS code as well... to get a better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions which I can think of.

**Solution 1:**
Try making a `<div>` of fixed size and put images in the background of `<div>`. So when you hover background image will be gif otherwise it will be a static image.

**Solution 2:**
If your images are loading dynamically then you should make your images all of the same sizes with CSS or without CSS (with any photo editor). If you can't make all of the images of the same sizes then at least make pair of images of the same size (e.g static and hover of one image should be the same size).

Comment: Happy to help, kindly upvote the answer. Good luck.